# Opencart pavblog latest module - take the latest from specific category

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

How can I modify the module so it takes only the articles from a specific category (ID = 35) of the articles?

The below code takes all the articles for the opencart module pavblog. I would like to change it so it does take only articles with category id of 35.

Please let me know how is it possible to change this code.

It was taken from catalog/controller/module folders in opencart.

```
<?php  
class Controllermodulepavbloglatest extends Controller {
    protected function index($setting) {
        static $module = 0;
        $this->load->model('pavblog/blog');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product'); 
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $this->language->load('module/pavblog');

        $this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');


        if( !defined("_PAVBLOG_MEDIA_") ){
            if (file_exists('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/pavblog.css')) {
                $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/pavblog.css');
            } else {
                $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/pavblog.css');
            }
            define("_PAVBLOG_MEDIA_",true);
        }

        $default = array(
            'latest' => 1,
            'limit' => 9
        );

        $this->data['width'] = $setting['width'];
        $this->data['height'] = $setting['height'];
        $this->data['cols']   = (int)$setting['cols'];  

        $this->data['tabs'] = array();



        $data = array(
            'sort'  => 'b.`created`',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'start' => 0,
            'limit' => $setting['limit']
        );

        if( $setting['tabs'] == 'featured' ){           
            $data['featured'] = 1;
            $blogs = $this->model_pavblog_blog->getListBlogs( $data );
            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_featured');
        }elseif( $setting['tabs'] == 'mostviewed' ){    
            $data['sort'] = 'b.`hits`';
            $blogs = $this->model_pavblog_blog->getListBlogs( $data );
            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_mostviewed');
        }else {
            $blogs = $this->model_pavblog_blog->getListBlogs( $data );
            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_latest');
        }


        $this->load->model('pavblog/category'); 
        $users = $this->model_pavblog_category->getUsers();

        foreach( $blogs as $key => $blog ){
            if( $blogs[$key]['image'] ){    
                $blogs[$key]['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($blog['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height'] );
            }else {
                $blogs[$key]['thumb'] = '';
            }                   

            $blogs[$key]['description'] = html_entity_decode($blog['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $blogs[$key]['author'] = isset($users[$blog['user_id']])?$users[$blog['user_id']]:$this->language->get('text_none_author');
            $blogs[$key]['category_link'] =  $this->url->link( 'pavblog/category', "path=".$blog['category_id'] );
            $blogs[$key]['comment_count'] =  10;
            $blogs[$key]['link'] =  $this->url->link( 'pavblog/blog','id='.$blog['blog_id'] );
        }


        if( isset( $setting['description'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')] ) ) {  
            $this->data['message'] = html_entity_decode($setting['description'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }else {
            $this->data['message'] = '';
        }



        $this->data['blogs'] = $blogs;
        $this->data['module'] = $module++;

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/pavbloglatest.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/pavbloglatest.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/pavbloglatest.tpl';
        }

    $this->render();
}

}
?>
```

The code you are referring to

```
<?php   
/******************************************************
 * @package Pav blog module for Opencart 1.5.x
 * @version 1.0
 * @author http://www.pavothemes.com
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) Feb 2013 PavoThemes.com <@emai:pavothemes@gmail.com>.All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2
*******************************************************/

/**
 * class ModelPavblogBlog 
 */
class ModelPavblogBlog extends Model {      


    public function __construct( $registry ){
        parent::__construct( $registry );
        $this->isInstalled();

    }
    /**
     * Get Blog Information by Id 
     */
    public function getInfo( $id ){

        $query = ' SELECT b.*,bd.title,bd.description,cd.title as category_title,bd.content  FROM '
                                . DB_PREFIX . "pavblog_blog b LEFT JOIN "
                                . DB_PREFIX . "pavblog_blog_description bd ON b.blog_id=bd.blog_id LEFT JOIN "
                                . DB_PREFIX . 'pavblog_category c ON c.category_id=b.category_id  LEFT JOIN ' 
                                . DB_PREFIX . 'pavblog_category_description cd ON (c.category_id=cd.category_id AND cd.language_id='.(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id').')' ;

        $query .=" WHERE bd.language_id=".(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id');
        $query .= " AND b.blog_id=".(int)$id;


        $query = $this->db->query( $query );
        $blog = $query->row;
        return $blog; 
    }

    /**
     * update hit time after read
     */
    public function updateHits( $id ){
        $sql = ' UPDATE '.DB_PREFIX.'pavblog_blog SET hits=hits+1 WHERE blog_id='.(int)$id;
        $this->db->query( $sql );
    }

    /**
     * get list of blogs in same category of current
     */
    public function getSameCategory( $category_id, $blog_id, $limit=10 ){
        $data = array(
            'filter_category_id' => $category_id,

            'not_in'           => $blog_id,
            'sort'               => 'created',
            'order'              => 'DESC',
            'start'              => 0,
            'limit'              => $limit
        );

        return $this->getListBlogs( $data );
    }

    /**
     * get total blog
     */
    public function getTotal( $data ){
        $sql = ' SELECT count(b.blog_id) as total FROM '
                                . DB_PREFIX . "pavblog_blog b LEFT JOIN "
                                . DB_PREFIX . "pavblog_blog_description bd ON b.blog_id=bd.blog_id  and bd.language_id=".(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')." LEFT JOIN "
                                . DB_PREFIX . 'pavblog_category c ON c.category_id=b.category_id  LEFT JOIN ' 
                                . DB_PREFIX . 'pavblog_category_description cd ON c.category_id=cd.category_id  and cd.language_id='.(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') ;

        $sql .=" WHERE bd.language_id=".(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id');

        if( isset($data['filter_category_id']) && $data['filter_category_id'] ){
            $sql .= " AND b.category_id=".(int)$data['filter_category_id'];
        }
        if( isset($data['filter_tag']) && $data['filter_tag'] ){
            $tmp = explode (",",$data['filter_tag'] );

            if( count($tmp) > 1  ){

                $t = array();
                foreach( $tmp as $tag ){
                    $t[] = 'b.tags LIKE "%'.$this->db->escape( $tag ).'%"';

                }
                $sql .= ' AND  '.implode(" OR ", $t ).' ';  

            }else {
                $sql .= ' AND b.tags LIKE "%'.$this->db->escape( $data['filter_tag'] ).'%"';
            }
        }

        $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
        return $query->row['total'];

    }

    /**
     *  get list blogs 
     */
    public function getListBlogs( $data ){

        $sql = ' SELECT b.*,bd.title,bd.description,cd.title as category_title FROM '
                                . DB_PREFIX . "pavblog_blog b LEFT JOIN "
                                . DB_PREFIX . "pavblog_blog_description bd ON b.blog_id=bd.blog_id  and bd.language_id=".(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id')." LEFT JOIN "
                                . DB_PREFIX . 'pavblog_category c ON c.category_id=b.category_id  LEFT JOIN ' 
                                . DB_PREFIX . 'pavblog_category_description cd ON c.category_id=cd.category_id  and cd.language_id='.(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') ;

        $sql .=" WHERE b.status = '1' AND bd.language_id=".(int)$this->config->get('config_language_id');

        if( isset($data['filter_category_id']) && $data['filter_category_id'] ){
            $sql .= " AND b.category_id=".(int)$data['filter_category_id'];
        }


        if( isset($data['filter_tag']) && $data['filter_tag'] ){
            $tmp = explode (",",$data['filter_tag'] );

            if( count($tmp) > 1  ){

                $t = array();
                foreach( $tmp as $tag ){
                    $t[] = 'b.tags LIKE "%'.$this->db->escape( $tag ).'%"';

                }
                $sql .= ' AND  '.implode(" OR ", $t ).' ';  

            }else {
                $sql .= ' AND b.tags LIKE "%'.$this->db->escape( $data['filter_tag'] ).'%"';
            }
        }

        if( isset($data['featured']) ){
            $sql .= ' AND featured=1 '; 
        }

        if( isset($data['not_in']) && $data['not_in'] ){
            $sql .= ' AND b.blog_id NOT IN('.$data['not_in'].')';
        }
        $sort_data = array(
            'bd.title',

            'b.hits',
            'b.`position`',
            'b.`created`',
            'b.created'
        );  
        if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
            if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
            }else {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
            }
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY b.`position`";   
        }

        if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
            $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(bd.title) DESC";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(bd.title) ASC";
        } 
        if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
            if ($data['start'] < 0) {
                $data['start'] = 0;
            }               

            if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
                $data['limit'] = 20;
            }   

            $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
        }


        $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
        $blogs = $query->rows;
        return $blogs; 
    }

    public function isInstalled() {
        $sql = " SHOW TABLES LIKE '".DB_PREFIX."pavblog_blog'";
        $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
        if( count($query->rows) <=0 ){ 
            $file = dirname(DIR_APPLICATION).'/admin/model/sample/module.php';
            if( file_exists($file) ){
                require_once( $file );
                $sample = new ModelSampleModule( $this->registry );
                $result = $sample->installSampleQuery( $this->config->get('config_template'),'pavblog', true );  

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public function getDefaultConfig(){



        return array(
            'children_columns' => '3',
            'general_cwidth' => '250',
            'general_cheight' => '250',
            'general_lwidth'=> '620',
            'general_lheight'=> '300',
            'general_sheight'=> '250',
            'general_swidth'=> '250',
            'general_xwidth' => '80',
            'general_xheight' => '80',
            'cat_show_hits' => '1',
            'cat_limit_leading_blog'=> '1',
            'cat_limit_secondary_blog'=> '5',
            'cat_leading_image_type'=> 'l',
            'cat_secondary_image_type'=> 's',
            'cat_show_title'=> '1',
            'cat_show_image'=> '1',
            'cat_show_author'=> '1',
            'cat_show_category'=> '1',
            'cat_show_created'=> '1',
            'cat_show_readmore' => 1,
            'cat_show_description' => '1',
            'cat_show_comment_counter'=> '1',

            'blog_image_type'=> 'l',
            'blog_show_title'=> '1',
            'blog_show_image'=> '1',
            'blog_show_author'=> '1',
            'blog_show_category'=> '1',
            'blog_show_created'=> '1',
            'blog_show_comment_counter'=> '1',
            'blog_show_comment_form'=>'1',
            'blog_show_hits' => 1,
            'cat_columns_leading_blog'=> 1,
            'cat_columns_leading_blogs'=> 1,
            'cat_columns_secondary_blogs' => 2,
            'comment_engine' => 'local',
            'diquis_account' => 'pavothemes',
            'facebook_appid' => '100858303516',
            'facebook_width'=> '600',
            'comment_limit'=> '10',
            'auto_publish_comment'=>0,
            'enable_recaptcha' => 1,
            'recaptcha_public_key'=>'6LcoLd4SAAAAADoaLy7OEmzwjrf4w7bf-SnE_Hvj',
            'recaptcha_private_key'=>'6LcoLd4SAAAAAE18DL_BUDi0vmL_aM0vkLPaE9Ob',
            'rss_limit_item' => 12,
            'keyword_listing_blogs_page'=>'blogs'

        );
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: can I see your `getListBlogs()` function?

Comment: you call this: `$blogs = $this->model_pavblog_blog->getListBlogs( $data );`, should be in a php file somewhere, I'd like to see that

Comment: No not that file, try wherever the code for this: `$this->load->model('pavblog/blog');` is

Comment: I have added all the code for the module what you have given me

Comment: if you try Limit by last date , it works for your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$data = array(
     'sort'  => 'b.`created`',
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'start' => 0,
     'limit' => $setting['limit']
);
```

to:

```
$data = array(
     'filter_category_id' => 35,
     'sort'  => 'b.`created`',
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'start' => 0,
     'limit' => $setting['limit']
);
```

I did some research on opencart and I think this should work. Initially, I didn't see the following code, which checks for a `filter_category_id` in the `getListBlogs()` function:

```
if( isset($data['filter_category_id']) && $data['filter_category_id'] ){
    $sql .= " AND b.category_id=".(int)$data['filter_category_id'];
}
```

Comment: I ll change it and see

Comment: Thank you for the help :) if you have any tips let me know

Comment: ok, no problem, I really need to see the code from this module: `$this->load->model('pavblog/blog');`

Comment: @Tom, see my revised answer

Comment: I have added the code you were referring...i hope that is

Comment: The entire blog module: http://www.pavothemes.com/opencart-modules/25-pav-blog-module.html

Comment: @Tom, Don't forget to accept answer.if this answer is useful.